# http get method with asp.net core and angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core Webapi project, where i have imported Angular through NPM. I haven't worked with this kind of setup before and might therefore be an easy question (i hope). How do i make an http request and show the response data to the user on front-end?

Is it just create an angular controller, where i make a `$http.get` or is there something with the ASP.NET Controllers Routes i have take a look at?

Controllers.cs:

```
Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is too broad. But still, I did a simple project to connect  Angular with WebAPI. Not .net Core. But it shouldn't matter.  Have a look . https://github.com/prabhakarreddy1234/TradingDashboardApp

Comment: Is your project only ASP.NET Core or with Angular?

Comment: No.  It's just ASP.Net Web API with Angular.  It doesn't matter if it's asp.net core or regular ASP.Net .  It's just a simple Web API controller being called from Angular.